# Why is `for i in {1..10}` different from `for ((i=1; i<=10; i++))`?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I wrote a simple code via bash script,

Code 1

```
for((i=1;i<=10;i++))
do
        echo $i 
        i=$((i+1))
        echo $i
        i=$((i+2))
done
```

output of Code 1

```
1
2
5
6
9
10
```

Code 2

```
for i in {1..10}
do
        echo $i 
        i=$((i+1))
        echo $i
        i=$((i+2))
done
```

output of Code 2

```
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
8
8
9
9
10
10
11
```

I'm just wondering, why outputs are not same ?
Thnx in advance

Comment: BTW, `{1..10}` isn't specific to for loops -- you can `echo {1..10}`, for example, or do something like  `mv {1..10} numbered_files/`. It's only the `(( INIT; CHECK; INCR ))` approach that's `for`-specific syntax, as documented in detail at https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not shorthand for each other: They're completely different code, and expected to behave in different ways.

`{1..10}` is just shorthand for `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`; when you run `for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`, you're explicitly assigning *those exact values* to `i` in turn, overwriting whatever else was previously there.

By contrast, `for ((i=1; i<=10; i++))` is providing three separate statements: An *initializer* (`i=1`), telling it what to do to start the loop; a *check* (`i<=10`) to tell it how to determine whether the loop is finished; and an *update* (`i++`), telling it what to do between loop iterations. These are completely arbitrary commands, and you can put any arithmetic expression you want in these positions.

Comment: Your and @choroba 's explanation was excellent and complete.
I really can not choose one of the answers as the main answer. So I give both of you a positive score.
Good luck.

Comment: Flip a coin, if that helps -- awarding the checkbox isn't just about points, it also changes how your question is represented to others to show that it has something that the person who asked it consists an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6):

With `in`, the variable iterates over the list. You can change its value in the loop, but when the next iteration starts, the next value will be assigned to it, regardless of what value you assigned to it. (And I can't imagine any other behaviour: should the shell try to guess how far in the list you want to jump? What if the value is repeated, or not present in the list at all?)

With the C-style `for`, the variable is initialized, and at each iteration, its value is changed and the condition checked. There's no list of values, only the condition to end the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `for((i=1;i<=10;i++))` loop could be rewritten as such:

```
i=1                              # for loop's 'i=1'

while [[ "${i}" -le 10 ]]        # for loop's 'i<=10'
do
        echo $i
        i=$((i+1))
        echo $i
        i=$((i+2))
        ((i++))                  # for loop's 'i++'
done
```

This generates ... you guessed it ...

```
1
2
5
6
9
10
```

---

Charles Duffy has already expanded the `for i in {1..10}` loop to show how that behaves.